# Rendering a local template with Sammy.js

Tags: sammy.js

I am using sammy for a web application that needs to render templates stored inline in the page. I am using a script tag to contain the markup, which is haml.

Is there a good, idiomatic way to render templates that are not loaded via ajax request? I have a solution, but I am not happy with it. $('#start_haml') is the script element containing the markup and $('#sammy_main') is the container to render into.

```
app.get '#/', (context) ->

context.load($('#start_haml')).then((data) ->
  context.interpolate(data, {helpers: view_helpers})
).replace('#sammy_main')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Aaron Quint for [answering me on the Sammy.js mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/sammyjs/browse_thread/thread/69fe4114660a4e69)

The answer is simple, but worth leaving here since it is not mentioned in the documentation.

```
context.render($('#start_haml'), {helpers: view_helpers})
  .replace '#sammy_main'
```

NB. The second parameter to render() is the view data.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked:

```
this.use('Template', "[object HTMLScriptElement]"); // If not view data are not rendered
[...]
var template = $('#tmpInmuebleDetalle')[0];
this.partial(template);
```